# Expect Script check /var/log/message

Tags: tcl, sh, expect

In the expected script, when I login remotely on a system via ssh then do `sudo su -`, I want to check in `/var/log/secure` for a specific string and show the output on the screen if that string exists or not (send "grep....)

```
expect << 'EOF'
    spawn ssh -q $env(U1)@$env(S1)
    expect "password:" {
        send $env(P1)\r
    }
    expect "$env(U1)@$env(S1)" {
        send "sudo su - \r"
    }
    expect "password" {
        send $env(P1)\r
    }

    expect  {
        "# " {
            send "grep 'pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by' /var/log/secure"
        }
        "Authentication failure" {
            send_user "Su ROOT  Fail ...... Fail\n"
            send \x03
        }
    }
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're searching for a specific string, you're best off using `fgrep`. If you only care whether the string is present, and not whether there's anything else around it, you use the `-q` option and a little shell trickery to get a result that it is easy to handle:

```bash
fgrep -q '....' /var/log/secure && echo FOUND || echo ABSENT
```

Next, you need to plug that into your expect script in a way that works. In particular, we need to ensure that the code will *not* run the search if a failure to elevate occurs:

```tcl
# Factored out for line-length reasons. :-)
set searchTerm "pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by"
expect  {
    "# " {
        send "fgrep -q '$searchTerm' /var/log/secure && echo FOUND || echo ABSENT"
    }
    "Authentication failure" {
        send_user "Su ROOT  Fail ...... Fail\n"
        send \x03
        #### STOP THE EXPECT SCRIPT RUNNING!
        close
        exit 1
    }
}
expect {
    "FOUND" {
        # ...
    }
    "ABSENT" {
        # ...
    }
}
```

The art of writing a good Expect script is in anticipating the failure modes. Also, you probably ought to use `send "exec sudo su -\r"` so that that the end of the elevated session is also the end of the overall session.